# How to get exactly what field contains using jQuery by parsing HTML platform Node.js

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, cheerio

I am trying to parse HTML tag `<blockquote>` and want to get the `id` attribute.

And in console I got an empty string, what should I do to fix it? Thanks in advance.

I need this output in this case : `m178043663`

HTML:

```
<blockquote id="" class="post-message">                                              
      УНИЖЕНИЯ ТРЕД<strong> WEBM&#47;MP4</strong>
</blockquote>
```

My attempt to parse this:

```
request('https://2ch.hk/b/',(error,response,body)=>{
  const $ = cheerio.load(body)
  const threadfind = $('blockquote').text()

  if(threadfind && threadfind.includes('WEBM'))
  { // thread find blockquote 

     const threadid= threadfind.includes("WEBM")
      var rtrrr = threadfind.attr('id')
     console.log(rtrrr)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution

```
 request('https://2ch.hk/b/',(error,response,body)=>{
      const $ = cheerio.load(body)
      const threadfind = $('blockquote')

      if(threadfind && threadfind.text().includes('WEBM'))
      { // thread find blockquote 
         const threadid= threadfind.attr('id')
         console.log(threadid)
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

As seen here

```
<blockquote id="" class="post-message">                                              
      УНИЖЕНИЯ ТРЕД<strong> WEBM&#47;MP4</strong>
</blockquote>
```

There was no `id` in `<blockquote>` element so it return empty string.

Also, this code here `const threadfind = $('blockquote').text()` makes your `threadfind` a string variable so you cannot get `id` out of this line `threadfind.attr('id')`

Here's [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/282625/) for getting an element id.

Comment: it sends me and error that text() is not a function. And I need to get` Id` in after `**If** equasion`

Comment: Sorry, I though you had multiple blockquote element.

But let me edit my answer.